# Show gridview total amount in a textbox which is outside gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `gridview` in which what I want is,

*When I insert one row with some values, I want to show its total value in the `textbox` which is outside the `gridview`*

What I tried is below,

I created a function for calculation of the textboxes. like below

```
private void GrandPaidTotal()
{
    float GTotal = 0f;

    for (int i = 0; i < GridPayInfo.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        String total = (GridPayInfo.Rows[i].FindControl("txtPayamt") as TextBox).Text;
        GTotal += Convert.ToSingle(total);
    }
    txtTotalPaidAmt.Value = GTotal.ToString();
}
```

and I called this function on `Page_load`. But while debugging I got error as

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

at line

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridPayInfo.Rows.Count; i++)
```

Kindly tell me, how to implement this.

**UPDATE**

logic of filling grid

```
protected void GridPayInfo_InsertCommand(object sender, GridRecordEventArgs e)
{
    int iRowCountPay = 0;

    if (Session["payInfo"] != null)
    {
        dtpayInfo = (DataTable)Session["payInfo"];
    }
    else
    {
        BindDataTable();
    }

    iRowCountPay = dtpayInfo.Rows.Count;
    DataRow newRowPay = dtpayInfo.NewRow();
    newRowPay["SR_NO"] = iRowCountPay + 1;

    newRowPay["TYPE_ID"] = Convert.ToString(e.Record["TYPE"]);
    //newRowPay["TYPE"] = Convert.ToString(e.Record["TYPE"]);
    newRowPay["TYPE"] = CF.ExecuteScaler2("Select type_desc from type_mst where Type_Code = 'AGR' and Type_Abbr ='" + Convert.ToString(e.Record["TYPE"]) + "'").ToString();
    newRowPay["VENDOR_NAME"] = Convert.ToString(e.Record["VENDOR_NAME"]);
    newRowPay["AGRMT_AMT"] = Convert.ToString(e.Record["AGRMT_AMT"]);
    newRowPay["PAYABLE_AMT"] = Convert.ToString(e.Record["PAYABLE_AMT"]);
    newRowPay["PAID_AMT"] = Convert.ToString(e.Record["PAID_AMT"]);
    newRowPay["EXP_TYPE_E_ID"] = Convert.ToString(e.Record["EXP_TYPE"]);
    newRowPay["EXP_TYPE"] = CF.ExecuteScaler2("select DESCRIPTION from fnd_flex_values_vl where FLEX_VALUE_MEANING = '" + Convert.ToString(e.Record["EXP_TYPE"]) + "'").ToString();
    newRowPay["REMARKS"] = Convert.ToString(e.Record["REMARKS"]);
    newRowPay["TRAN_DT"] = Convert.ToString(e.Record["TRAN_DT"]);
    newRowPay["VOUCHER_NO"] = Convert.ToString(e.Record["VOUCHER_NO"]);
    newRowPay["CHEQUE_NO"] = Convert.ToString(e.Record["CHEQUE_NO"]);
    newRowPay["CHEQUE_DT"] = Convert.ToString(e.Record["CHEQUE_DT"]);
    newRowPay["CHQ_FAV_NAME"] = Convert.ToString(e.Record["CHQ_FAV_NAME"]);

    dtpayInfo.Rows.Add(newRowPay);
    GridPayInfo.DataSource = dtpayInfo;
    GridPayInfo.DataBind();
    AddToViewState("GridPayInfo");
}

  public void AddToViewState(string strGrid)
{
    if (strGrid == "GrdPartyInfo")
    {
        Session["partyInfo"] = dtPartyInfo;
    }
    if (strGrid == "GridPayInfo")
    {
        Session["payInfo"] = dtpayInfo;
    }

    if (strGrid == "GridExpInfo")
    {
        Session["ExpInfo"] = dtExpInfo;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your datagrid may not loaded and is null

Comment: @VisakhVA: at first there are no rows, so it shows **null**. So is there any other way to implement this ?

Comment: you could have a null checking and return like 'if(GridPayInfo == null ) return;'

Comment: Do this calculation in ItemBound of the grid, and make total property which increments with every row.

Comment: @mybirthname: why did u deleted your answer ? also will the same code will be added on `itembound` ?

Comment: Because it is too long to explain, check ItemBound event of grid in the web. Or just calculate the text boxes value from DataSet which Bind the grid or whatever you bind it.

Comment: @mybirthname: you mean to say `Databound` or `RowDataBound` ?

Comment: @mybirthname: It would be great if you show some code or some  helpful links on how to achieve this, that would be much great.

Comment: @mybirthname: I tried something like this with your code. `for (int j = 0; j < GridPayInfo.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            String total = GridPayInfo.Rows[j].Cells[6].Text;
            GTotal += Convert.ToSingle(total);
        }

        txtTotalPaidAmt.Value = GTotal.ToString();` but the value outside the textbox is not getting set

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is easier to use the `OnRowDataBound` event.

```
    int totalCount = 0;
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
            totalCount += Convert.ToInt32(drv["txtPayamt"]);
        }
        TextBox1.Text = "Total count is: " + totalCount;
    }
```

UPDATE

Did some further testing. It appears that the above code does not work well if the GridView contains more complex functionality (edit, insert). It calls `RowDataBound` more than once per row.
This new snippet works by looping the rows and using `FindControl`. This function needs to be called DataBind and after adding a new row.

```
    private void countItemsInGrid()
    { 
        int totalCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < SettingsB.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            TextBox tb = SettingsB.Rows[i].FindControl("txtPayamt") as TextBox;
            try
            {
                totalCount += Convert.ToInt32(tb.Text);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
        TextBox1.Text = "Total count is: " + totalCount;
    }
```

Comment: let me try and check

Comment: at `txtTotalPaidAmt.Value = totalCount;` I am getting error as `cannot implicitly convert int to string` at `totalCount`

Comment: I resolved that int error. But the value is not getting set into the textbox. why ?

Comment: Is the value of TextBox1 overwritten somewhere? For testing add `Response.Write("Total count is: " + totalCount + "<br>");`, you'll see that the values add up.

Comment: after value is been set, the page is getting postbacked. that is why the values doesnt gets set. So what should I do in this case ?

Comment: That shouldn't matter, `RowDataBound` is always called, even after postback. Can you show the code as to how you fill the grid?

Comment: By insert command and then saving the code on buttonclick i fill the grid

Comment: just by debugging, I saw the grid was getting rebinded. I dont know why it was getting like that.

Comment: Updated my answer with new findings.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, m out of office now will try tomorrow and update u accordingly

Comment: When I run the page, I get error as `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` at line `(int i = 0; i < GridPayInfo.Rows.Count; i++)`  because there is no row at all in the grid

Comment: Is `GridPayInfo` nested or inside another control? Because even if it has no rows the result would be 0 (no looping of rows), not an error.

Comment: No, the gridview is not nested. Can you give me ur email id, I will mail you the full code for that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125690/discussion-between-vdwwd-and-nad).

Comment: sorry, I am busy right now. will chat after some time. I will ping you.

Comment: need to ask one thing, Can we bind one value from first grid to second grid. let me know if we can do that or no ? I get value in session, but how to insert that value in second grid.

Comment: Yes, if you mean you want to use a column value of parent to get the content for the child from a database for example.

Comment: Yes, I cracked that using JavaScript.. but still I am not able to set the total value in that textbox, will u be available tomorrow so that we can chat and finish that off as I am out of office now

Comment: sure, but we could have different time zones. But you can post a message in chat and I'll read it

Comment: Yes, I stay in India and it's 10pm now here. Okay. Will surely post what I tried and what wrongs happening with my code. Take care